# how can i stop mysql from updating a table automatically

Tags: mysql, node.js, cron

am running a cronjob to update a user table every midnight, when I stop the Nodejs application, the table keep updating by itself, and have already stop the application.

here is the nodejs code I use for the job

```js
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const logger = require("../helpers/logger");
const { updateUser } = require("../helpers/user");
const db = require("../models/db");



const job = new CronJob('* * * * *', async function() {
    
    db.query("UPDATE sponsored_posts SET post_status = 0", (err, data) => {
        if (err) logger.debug(err)
    });

    db.query("DELETE FROM sponsored_posts", (err, data) => {
        if (err) logger.debug(err)
    });


    //EXPIRING USER
    db.query("SELECT * FROM all_users WHERE membership_expired > 0", async (err, data) => {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            //FIlter Through All User
            //Deduct While They Havent Expired
            await data.map(async user => {
                await updateUser({
                        uid: parseInt(user.uid),
                        membership_expired: user.membership_expired - 1
                })
                
            })
        }
    })
    
    db.query("SELECT * FROM all_users WHERE membership_expired = 0", async (err, data) => {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            //FIlter Through All User
            //Set Can Purchase To 1
            await data.map(async user => {
                await updateUser({
                    uid: parseInt(user.uid),
                    can_purchase: 1
                })
                
            })
        }
    });
    
}, null, false, "Africa/Lagos");

job.start();
```

Comment: Did you remove the cron job?

Comment: since have already turn off the nodejs application, the cronjob wont work
but MySQL keep updating the table at the specific time I set in the cronjob on the nodejs script.

and have already turn off the nodejs application

Comment: My question was about the system cron, I understood that you stopped Node.js

Comment: What are you asking about the system cron?
am using this cron package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

have already turn off the application, still yet MySQL is updating the user table

Comment: still yet MySQL is updating.... means you have a cron in service. If you are sure Node.js cron is out of service, that's you should have a job in the system cron. That saod are-you sure Node.js cron is done?

Comment: have already stop the nodejs application on the cpanel , so I don't expect any job to run, since the job Is on the script and have already turn of the script

Comment: Ok you have mysql that's udpate a table without job ! ... I can nothing for you.

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: Yes, I understood that you don't understad me. Communication is a difficult art. It"s late (for me), hope sb else will be able to help better than me.